# When called from my main method, my toString method in child class is returning zero

Tags: java, abstract, tostring

I have the assignment to use an abstract class as a superclass "Shape". It has three classes that extend that class, Triangle, Circle, and Square. Each class is supposed to compute the area and the perimeter of these shapes. I have things working when I `System.out.println(shapeArray[i].computeArea());` in a for loop. But when I try and call the toString method from the child classes in that for loop everything returns as "0". I appreciate anybody taking the time to help out, as I am pretty stuck here. I feel like I have read, and re-read threads, and my textbook all day. I feel like there is just some dumb mistake here that I cannot see.

**Shape.java**

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    private double radius;
    final private double PI = 3.14159;
    private double circumfrence;
    private double area;

    Circle(double radius) {

        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeArea() {
        double radSquared = radius * radius;
        double area = PI * radSquared;
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double computePerimeter() {
        circumfrence = 2 * PI * radius;
        return circumfrence;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Area of Circle: " +area + "\nCircumfrence of Circle: " + circumfrence;
    }

}
```

**Triangle.java**

```
public class Triangle extends Shape {

    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    private double area;
    private double perimeter;


    Triangle (double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeArea() {
          double s =(side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
          double area= Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
          area = this.area;
          return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double computePerimeter() {
        perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;
        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Area of Triangle: " + area+ "\nPerimeter of Triangle: " + perimeter;
    }

}
```

**Circle.java**

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    private double radius;
    final private double PI = 3.14159;
    private double circumfrence;
    private double area;

    Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeArea() {
        double radSquared = radius * radius;
        double area = PI * radSquared;
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double computePerimeter() {
        circumfrence = 2 * PI * radius;
        return circumfrence;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Area of Circle: " +area + "\nCircumfrence of Circle: " + circumfrence;
    }

}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private double length;
    private double height;
    private double sumOfLength;
    private double sumOfHeight;
    private double area;
    private double perimeter;

    Rectangle(double length, double height) {
        this.height = height;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeArea() {
        area = (length * height);
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double computePerimeter() {
        sumOfLength = length * 2;
        sumOfHeight = height * 2;
        perimeter = sumOfLength + sumOfHeight;
        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Area of Rectangle: " +area + "\nPerimeter of Rectangle: " + perimeter;
    }

}
```

**ShapeArray.java**

```
public class ShapeArray {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Shape shapeArray[] = new Shape[3];

        Circle circ = new Circle(9);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 6);
        Triangle tri = new Triangle(6, 8, 12);

        shapeArray[0] = circ;
        shapeArray[1] = rect;
        shapeArray[2] = tri;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.println(shapeArray[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Area of Circle: 0.0
Circumfrence of Circle: 0.0
Area of Rectangle: 0.0
Perimeter of Rectangle: 0.0
Area of Triangle: 0.0
Perimeter of Triangle: 0.0
```

Comment: you do not call computation methods before toString, that's why

Comment: 1. Your Shape class shouldn't have these 3 protected fields. Why would a shape have a triangle, a circle and a rectangle? 2. None of the classes should have fields for their preimeter and area. The computeArea method should compute and return the area.

Comment: also, some of your computation methods store result in local variable instead of class field

Comment: Could you explain what you mean exactly by not calling computation method before toString? @AlexanderPavlov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you must call in for loop `shapeArray[i].computeArea()` and `shapeArray[i].computePerimeter()` before `shapeArray[i].toString()`.

In **ShapeArray.java**

```
//other code

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    shapeArray[i].computeArea();
    shapeArray[i].computePerimeter()
    System.out.println(shapeArray[i].toString());
}

//other code
```

It prints 0 because you don't call calculation of perimeter and area for class instance before print it. But I also recommend reviewing your code that it does not use unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 0):

your class `Triangle.computeArea` method change the from `area = this.area;` to `this.area=area;`
Other class like this.